# python: how to query multiple mysql databases using pandas.read_sql_query

Tags: python, pymysql

As mentioned above I need to query several databases with all the same schema using `pandas.read_sql_query`. I've tried to create loop over all the dbs and run on the fly the sql statement that would result in something like this:

`USE db_test_1; SELECT * from test`

That's what I've done so far:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES LIKE '%test_%'")
cursor.close()
dbs = [v.replace("'", "") for (v, ) in cursor]

for db in dbs[:100]:
    temp = "USE " + db + ";"
    fd = open('my_query.sql')
    query = fd.read()
    fd.close
    sql = temp + query
    data = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn)
    print(data)
```

Gives an error saying that the mysql syntax is wrong. Do you have any idea how to handle it or point me to the error?

Many thanks

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: `5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log`

Comment: And what are the contents of `my_query.sql`

Comment: `SELECT (SELECT field_1 from tab1), (SELECT field_2 FROM tab2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies with your `my_query.sql` file.

```
SELECT (SELECT * from tab1), (SELECT * from tab2)
```

The above is not valid SQL; a subselect can only return a single column. To do this, you would need to join the two subselects in the `FROM` clause. Which columns you do this on will be entirely dependent on your schema and the needed relation.

**Update:**

Okay, so the problem here seems to be more about how you're dealing with the query. Your cursor object is connected to a single database. Not the entire database server.

That means that your cursor object cannot use the `use` keyword here. You need to create a new connection and cursor object for each database you want to connect to.

Comment: thanks @Jacobm001 sorry for that.. the query is more like this:
`SELECT (SELECT field_1 from tab1), (SELECT field_2 FROM tab2)`
tab1 and tab2 don't have an id to join

Comment: ... and it runs successfully

Comment: @Codutie: does it work if you add 'FROM dual' to the end of that? I'm wondering if SQL Alchemy doesn't appreciate the lack of `FROM` clause.

Comment: no that's doesn't help.. if I run only the `my_query.sql` it works smoothly.. but the first part in the loop `temp = "USE " + db + ";"` and then the concat `sql = temp + query` cause the problem

Comment: Have you tried printing out the results of `sql` to the screen and running that?

Comment: that's the output of the third one f.eg:

```USE db_test_3;SELECT 
(SELECT field1 FROM tab1) field1,
(SELECT field2 FROM tab2) field2```